# Android studio gitignore won't ignore .iml

Tags: android, git, gitignore

Iv'e added:

```
*.iml
```

to all of the gitignore files in my project.
They are still being tracked, even after committing the .gitignore.

Answer (score 26):

The safe option is to remove the iml file from your staging index.

`git rm --cached <path to iml file>`

git will track the files sometimes even if you added the file which shouldn't be tracked in .gitignore

In that case you should remove the cache first then add all.

***Important : Before, commit or stash your current changes***

```
$ git rm -r --cached .
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "file tracking - changed"
```

Comment: git rm -f -r --cached .

Comment: This answer should be may break things in a code base and hence should not be here, or the author should add a warning.

Comment: Future readers: don't be afraid of this answer: It does **not** require a later commit where all-project files are added again, polluting the git history. After all the files did not change in between, so this answer really suggests the right thing.

Comment: @spawn yes it does, this answer is not stable.

Answer (score 0):

When you added them one time, they will keep tracked!

You have to retrieve all commits till the one where you commited the .iml files.

Here is a good post on SF about reseting commits in git:
[How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit)

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you linked to documentation and/or previous Stackoverflow answers to this FAQ.